# Google Now Launcher is not displayed in Bluestacks emulator

Tags: applications, launcher, google-now, default-applications, bluestacks

I have latest version of Bluestacks emulator(v 0.9.25.5401) installed on my Windows PC 64bit. I installed [Google Now laucher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.launcher&hl=en) from the playstore in the bluestacks. And after installing the launcher it requested to download also the [Google search](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox&hl=en) app which I don't want but installed it anyway.

After successfully installed both the apps I opened the Google Now laucher and it showed me to clear defaults of my previously installed Apex launcher and press Home button. I did clear defaults and after pressing home button Google Now laucher is not displayed in the list.

Its not available also in the Settings menu. I can access them only in the menu drawer and in desktop two icons are created. But I click the icon it shows to select a default launcher for Home which shows only three other 3rd party lauchers but not Google Now.

[image: Settings_Screenshot]
[image: Home_select_screenshot]

<sub>Screenshots - Click to enlarge images</sub>

How to make `Google Now` launcher as the default launcher for Bluestacks? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restarting the PC fixed the problem. I restarted the Bluestacks and also tried Restart option from the tray icon options menu. But restarting the PC fixed the issue and the fourth option Google Now Laucher is shown in the list. Wierd I dont know how this fixed it.(May be some registry or some other system reset changes required with restart.)

[image: Screenshot_launcher_selection]